# controlling paintGL method - How to decide what to paint?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, paintevent

I want to control the paintGL method by a keypress-event. The aim is show an additional point by pushing return. 
In other words: I have painted a nice background scene and now i want to push return (in a lineEdit) and there appears a red point in front of the already shown background.

//MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    glWidget = new GLWidget;
    connect(ui->lineEdit,   SIGNAL(returnPressed()),    glWidget, SLOT (set_draw()));
}
```

//glwidget.h

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "cstdio" 

class MainWindow;

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
 MainWindow *myMainWindow;   

 public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    //~GLWidget;

    int draw;

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

public slots:
    void set_draw();
 };
#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

//glwidget.cpp

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    draw = 0;
}
//-------------
void GLWidget::set_draw()  //this SLOT is activated by pushing return
{
draw = 1;
updateGL(); //updating paintGL...
}
//-------------
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    swapBuffers();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/* drawing a lot of stuff*/

    if( draw == 1 )
    {
/*the following messagebox is shown at the screen*/
QMessageBox* Box = new QMessageBox();
Box->setText("Bert");
Box->show();

/*this big red point is NOT shown at the screen*/
        glPointSize(30);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(45,45,0);
        glEnd();
    }

}
```

Can someone explain, why this is not working? The red point does not appear... Is the value of `int draw` influenced by the paintGL method?

Comment: When you debug, does it actually step into the `draw==1` conditional?  Also are you sure your viewport size has position 45, 45 within the bounds of the screen?

Comment: Yes, it does step into draw==1 condition, but goes immediatly back to zero. So I think, the point is "shown" a few milliseconds, but I`m not sure...  Viewport is ok. Outside the if-condition the point is shown.

Comment: I would try changing your variable name then, if it goes back to 0 then it means it only draws for one frame.

Comment: no change... same behaviour with different variable name.

Comment: Is the code you have posted everything that is using your `draw` variable, or is there some other code that could potentially set it elsewhere?  Also, are you only using one `GLWidget` or could you potentially be creating a new one every update?

Comment: "draw" is only used by the shown code. GLWidget is created once in the MainWindow costructor.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL you always redraw the whole scene. Store the additional point in some array. When drawing you iterate over that array and draw the points according to the array's content.

Comment: I defined an array (100,100,0) in the set_draw-method and changed paintGL as follows:     void GLWidget::paintGL()
    {
        swapBuffers();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glPointSize(3);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
         glVertex3f(point_array[0], point_array[1], point_array[2]);
        glEnd();
    } This leads to a point at (0,0,0), which means the array is set to zero as previously the "draw" variable...

Comment: @edcrfv45: Well, in that case a single variable would have sufficed. I was suggesting an array so that you could add several points, not just one.